# How can I give dynamic width for ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wish to give width (ul) to dynamically depending on how many elements there are in the list.

What is wrong what they are doing?

I have this sample: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNQYVa)

```js
$('.sub-menu').each(function() {
  var liItems = $(this);
  var Sum = 0;
  if (liItems.children('li').length >= 1) {
    $(this).children('li').each(function(i, e) {
      Sum += $(e).outerWidth(true);
    });
    $(this).width(Sum + 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sub-menu li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `display: inline-block;` on your `<ul>` and on your list elements (no need for floating):

```css
.sub-menu {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0
}
.sub-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
</ul>
<br />
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: or simply `flex:1;`

Comment: yes but at this moment ... both my lists have the same width, I do not want it ... I want to be the limited width depending on how many items are

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/v1HIujAiBLN now i hope you understand better

Comment: ?@Cristi why than don't you simply use `display: inline-block;` for all your UL and inner LI elements? I don't get your question any more..

Comment: I work in the project as if the exchange float: left to display: inline-block, it hurt and I need different things float: left

Comment: @Cristi your English is really hard to understand :) Sorry

Comment: so I tried to keep going but I wish float: left and width: 25%

Comment: Ok I don't think I get what you want... O:) sry

Comment: @andreas Please let float: left and width: 25%, so I want an example

Comment: @Cristi if you struggle with your English, perhaps showing an image of all the desired results could help us to better understand your requirement...?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the items to be exactly 25% of the page width, it gets a little tricky using css only. But I'm pretty sure your goals can be achieved without resorting to javascript.

One way is to fake it, by putting the background color on the `<li>` elements instead of the `<ul>`, and removing space between them. Technically, the list is still the full width of the page, as ilustrated by the border, so this solution wont work it that is a problem.

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border: dashed 1px grey;
}
.sub-menu:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
.sub-menu li {
  background: red;
  list-style: none; /* hides the bullet */
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>
```

If, however, you can accept a fixed witdth on the `<li>` elements, like `width: 200px` then andreas' suggested answer is a better and cleaner solution.